# Date column populating from CSV to table behaving differently using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have CSV file

```
**date column**
06/04/1999
06/04/2000
.
.
.06/04/2017
```

I'm just loading this file from Csv file to Database table using SSIS

> > Flat file source to OLEDB Destination

where date column is absolutely DT_STR and SQL Table date column  is varchar(50)

But it is behaving differently when I load sometimes it is populating like

```
  **date column**
    06/04/1999
    06/04/2000
```

and some other times like

```
 **date column**
    1999-04-06
    2000-04-06
```

I'm just trying to load the same what ever is there in Flat file but why it is giving "-" sometimes .
Can any one please suggest me why it behaving differently each time . 
It doesn't have any conversions(like Derived Columns) in SSIS

Comment: what is the data type in `metadata` after the source? The first is more like in `VARCHAR` type in your destination, but for the 2nd loads, it is more like column is in `DATE` format

Comment: No the meta data is same as 1st load @LONG

Comment: Have you validated that the dates in the files are always the same format, or are those sometimes formatted one way, sometimes the other? Since you are just importing the data as a string, this is important to know.

Comment: how I can validate the dates from file if I see file is looking same with same date format DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: @mohan111 it may contains some rows with different formats, if both columns are varchar and there is no transformation while the data import process, the problem must be in the flat file. take a look as my provided answer, and give me a reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to convert these values to DateTime then to String with desired format `yyyy-MM-dd` using a `ScriptComponent Transformation`**

1. Create a `Flat File connection manager` and an `OLEDB Connection Manager` (Source and Destination)
2. Add a `DataFlow Task`
3. In the `DataFlow Task` add a `Flat File Source` , `Script Component` , `OLEDB Destination`
4. your DataFlow should look like `Source --> Script --> Destination`
5. In the Script component Mark the Time column as input( assuming it's name is `inDateColumn`) and add an Output Column (ex: `OutDateColumn`) of String `DT_STR`
6. In the Script Write The Following Code: *(using Vb.net)*

   ```
   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)  

       If Not Row.inDateColumn_IsNull AndAlso _
           Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.inDateColumn.Trim) Then

           ' You can add more formats inside the following method

           Row.OutDateColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.inDateColumn.Trim,New String(){"yyyy-MM-dd","dd/MM/yyyy"},New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("En-GB"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

       Else

           Row.OutDateColumn_IsNull = True

       End If

   End Sub
   ```
7. Map `OutDateColumn` to the destination column

Comment: why i will use script task.how i can data integrity in file itself.Can you please explain the what are steps need to take

Comment: @mohan111 i am talking about script component transformation which is a dataflow task component, not the script task.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/comparing-the-script-task-and-the-script-component

Comment: Script component contains a sub named ProcessInputRow that will run on each row in the dataflow task https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-types/creating-a-synchronous-transformation-with-the-script-component

Comment: In my answer i used the [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) which convert a string value to datetime baeed on an array of formats. Then i am using `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` to convert the datevalue to a date string with the format above. So all values will have the same format in the output